# Choosing between Engine.IO and SockJS

Tags: sockjs, engine.io

How to choose between Engine.IO and SockJS? Are they competing and this is just a matter of taste and opinion, or there is some logic when choosing between them?

Answer (score 0):

Engine.io and SockJS are quite similar and both have been well tested in the industry. SockJS has libraries for a wider range of different environments/languages (including Node.js) whereas Engine.io is geared primarily towards Node.js (though there are unofficial implementations for other languages).

Engine.io was written in plain JavaScript whereas the Node.js version of SockJS is written in CoffeeScript.